# What is can draw concurrently interface builder?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I have never used Can draw concurrently option mentioned in iterface builder. See image below:

[image]

Can someone explain me its use and purpose?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use it to inform AppKit that your `NSView` subclass' `-drawRect:` instance method *may* be called from a secondary thread.

It's 10.6+. When/if AppKit renders views asynchronously, `-drawRect:` is performed using concurrent blocks, and your `-drawRect:` will be called from a secondary thread. This means your subclass' implementation must be threadsafe (for compatibility, it is disabled by default).

See also `-[NSView setCanDrawConcurrently:]` for details, because there are few things required to actually enable this behaviour. As well, it shouldn't imply that AppKit is threadsafe or that its `NSView` subclasses are designed to support this functionality - It's designed for *your* heavy drawing.

Comment: Note that as of OS X 10.8 and iOS 6.0, setting the new `drawsAsynchronously` property on the view's layer may provide sufficient performance without the complication of making `drawRect:` thread-safe.  On OS X you'll need to use a layer-backed view to use `drawsAsynchronously`.

Comment: @robmayoff nice tip +1. have you by chance measured this or come across a good write-up? i have been writing threadsafe concurrent renderers for a while. i figure it's an area a lot of people would want to avoid :)

Comment: I haven't played with it.  The *Optimizing 2D Graphics and Animation Performance* video from [WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) discusses it, starting around 31m24s.

Answer (score 3):

The option is for view that support threaded drawing for example `NSProgressIndicator`. If can Draw Concurrently is checked then drawRect can be invoked from a background thread for that view. Refer [NSView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html) class reference.
[**None of the AppKit's views support this (except for NSButton and NSProgressIndicator, but they have separate APIs for this for historical reasons).**](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/296949-strange-error-solved-by-turning-off-non-contiguous-layout.html#297067)